# Getting complete stack trace from application while using Transactional annotation

Tags: java, spring, exception

I am using spring Transactional annotation which is overriding custom exception:
 Application exception overriden by commit exception

lets say

```
@Transactional
method A() {
try {

 } catch (MyException e) {
   throw MyException(e.getMessage, e);
 }  
}
```

Now exception I got from code which is calling A is transaction rollback exception.
I want exact exception thrown by code, but Apache ExceptionUtils.getRootCause is returning transaction rollback messages which doesn't clarify anything.

How can I propagate exact application exception to caller method in this case?

Comment: Can you provide the calling method code ? MyException class it is extending which Exception class or RuntimeException class ?